# Concurrent git clone and fetch

Tags: ruby, git, unix, concurrency

I have 10 processes running on the same machine that at any time can run a `git clone` and a `git fetch` on the same git repo.

Obviously this is a problem as `git clone` will raise a "`directory already exist` and git fetch will raise something along the lines of `expected ref to be abcdfg but was hijklm` on subsequent requests. Often these requests will happen at the exact same time, so checking if the folder exists won't work, as git can be in the middle of creating it.

My question is: Is there a way I can check whether Git is currently cloning or currently fetching something? Then I can code my program to wait for the existing fetch to finish until moving on.

I'm running Ubuntu 12 LTS, if that helps, and my processes are coded in Ruby, although that doesn't matter much.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Your processes should be governed by a 'master' of some sort that delegates the work out to the different processes. With this approach, you can implement some form of mutex to prevent this type of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

For existing repositories (so during `fetch`), when Git is operating, it writes a file to `.git/index.lock`. Your processes should wait for that file to be cleaned up before running a new command.